# How to perform Dickey Fuller Test for First Order Integration?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, spyder, statsmodels

I am trying to perform an augmented Dickey Fuller test on the first integration of a variable, but I keep getting a Missing data error no matter what I do

Code:

```
texas = pd.read_stata('texas.dta')
texas['dtex'] = texas['txnag'] - texas['txnag'].shift(1)
texas['dtex'].replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).fillna(0)

dtec = adfuller(texas['dtex'].values)
```

And I get this output:

```
MissingDataError: exog contains inf or nans
```

What am I doing wrong? I guess it must be obvious, but I have no idea whatsoever.

Comment: `replace` doesn't work in-place unless your specify it. As per [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) use `inplace=True`

Comment: I have also tried clearing the na's with    `.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna( ) ` and nothing changes

Comment: Same issue as my latest comment :)

Comment: `.replace` returns a new `series`. Assign the returned value back: Use `texas['dtex'] = texas['dtex'].replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).fillna(0)`